# Pandas groupby cumsum from last to first

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

We can create a Serial Number (Index non 0) as: `dfm["serial"] = dfm.groupby("token").cumcount()+1`

This will create serial as below:

|  | token | serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 295368217 | 1 |
| 1 | 294638348 | 2 |
| 2 | 165168249 | 3 |
| 3 | 425388540 | 4 |
| 4 | 284673354 | 5 |

But how can I create serial in reverse order? as below:

|  | token | serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 295368217 | 5 |
| 1 | 294638348 | 4 |
| 2 | 165168249 | 3 |
| 3 | 425388540 | 2 |
| 4 | 284673354 | 1 |

**Rows are dynamic**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ty this:

```
df["serial"] = df["serial"].values[::-1]
```